# MSAL v1 after logout click on login button it is directly login without asking credential

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I'm using the below version of angular and MSAL for login flow,

```
"@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
"@azure/msal-angular": "^1.1.2",
"msal": "^1.4.4"
```

**issue:** once I click on logout it is taking me to log out screen which is current behave but when I click on the login button I'm calling the loginRedirect() method for login but it directly login to the application without asking credential.
this issue happens only on crome when Block third-party cookies are enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue is occurring because you are not clearing your session or token from your localstorage.
When you logout you must clear the cookies and local session of your token from the localStorage.

MSAL provides a logout method in v1 that clears the cache in browser storage and redirects the window to the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) sign-out page. After sign-out, Azure AD redirects back to the page that invoke logout by default. You can configure the URI to which it should redirect after sign-out by setting postLogoutRedirectUri. This URI should be registered as a redirect Uri in your application registration.
Learn more here about redirect [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=angular1#sign-out-with-a-redirect).

In your `app.module.ts` file add this code:

```
@NgModule({                                                                                   
 imports: [
  MsalModule.forRoot({
   auth: {
    clientId: 'your_app_id',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: "your_app_logout_redirect_uri"
  }
 })
]
})
```

In your component.ts add this code `this.authService.logout();`

Comment: I have call logout method it is working fine on normal browser but when open application on chrome Incognito mode and when 'Block third-party cookies' is enabled logout not working

Comment: Google chrome performs differently in incognito mode than other browsers; It blocks cross-site cookies. Azure AD B2C login issue in incognito mode will work by enabling cookies in the google chrome setting.
-> Chrome settings -> Privacy and Security -> Cookies and other sites data -> Allow all cookies.

Comment: Agree, but we can not tell customers about this setting.